# If $p$ is a prime and $P$ is a a subgroup of order $p$, then |$N_{S_n}(P)$| = $p(p-1)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

> If $p$ is a prime and $P$ is a a subgroup of $S_p$ of order $p$, then $|N_G(P)| = p(p-1)$, where $G=S_p$.

This is what I have done:

$P$ is a cyclic subgroup of order $p$ generated by a $p$-cycle. For every $a$, $b$ ∈ $P$, $a$, $b$ are conjugate since they have the same cycle type.

But I don't know how to do next. The hint is:

> Argue that every conjugate of $P$ contains exactly $p-1$ $p$-cycles and use the formula for the number of  $p$-cycles to compute the index of $N_G(P)$ in $S_p$.

I don't know what "contains exactly $p-1$ $p$-cycles" means. Does it mean my idea above?

If so, $p-1$=|$S_p$|/|$N_G(P)$|, and |$N_G(P)$| = $p(p-2)!$. That's so weird.

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

> I don't know what "contains exactly $p−1$ $p$-cycles" means

Well, what does the cyclic group generated by a $p$-cycle look like?  There are a total of $p$ elements.  One of them is the identity, and the rest  are $p$-cycles.  So there are $p - 1$ of these $p$-cycles in any such subgroup.

Of course, all the conjugates $g P g^{-1}$ of $P$ are subgroups generated by a $p$-cycle.

> Does it *[the hint]* mean my idea above *[that every $p$-cycle is conjugate to every other]*?

No, as I've explained above.  But your idea **is** important to solving this problem.

Use the two ideas above to count the number of $p$-cycles in $S_p$ in two different ways, and then see if you can solve for $|N_{S_p}(P)|$.